# post method error nodejs req.body is returns {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, curl

When using cURL or Postman, everything works as expcted

```html
 curl  -d 'username=Johny Sample&title=My First Post&description=We want some help cleaning up after the hurricane&postID=Johny Sample_1' http://localhost:3000/NewPost
```

Requester Results

```js
{"posterID":"Johny Sample","title":"My First Post","description":"We want some help cleaning up after the hurricane"}
```

Server Results

```js
req.body == { 
    username: 'Johny Sample',
       title: 'My First Post',
    description: 'We want some help cleaning up after the hurricane',
    postID: 'Johny Sample_1' 
      }
```

**Not Working from Browser**

**

```js
function gatherData()
 {
  var retData  ='title='+el("title").value+'';
  retData      +='&description='+el('description').value+'';
  postID    = 'Johny Sample_1';
  return    retData;
 }
 function save() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    a = xhttp.responseText;
       }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/NewPost", true);
  var sendData = gatherData();
    xhttp.send(sendData);
 }
```

**

Requester Results

null

Server Results

{}
 {}

**Server Side Code**

```js
  app.post('/NewPost', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var post  = {};
  post.posterID  = req.body.username;
  post.title = req.body.title;
  post.description= req.body.description;
  post.ID  = req.body.ID;
  console.log(post);
  res.send(post);
 })
```

Comment: Have you checked `req.query` instead of `req.body` when hitting the url through browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add HTTP header for POST

```
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/NewPost", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var sendData = gatherData();
xhttp.send(sendData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I was unfamiliar with this Content type options...thanks again!!